# how to stop data from adding into the database even when the textboxes are empty in asp?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, database, validation

I am trying to validate three textboxes, all of them are just text field. They are all connected to a database with sqlserver.

Now I want to know how to stop the form from adding empty records into my database when its still empty. I have some Javascript validation, which tells the user that the field is empty, but after you click okay for the message box, the page refreshes and an empty record is added.

If anyone could help me with a bit of code that'd be great.

My javascript looks like this:

```
    function myAddFunction() {
        var a = document.forms["form1"]["txtFirstName"].value;
        var b = document.forms["form1"]["txtLastName"].value;
        var c = document.forms["form1"]["txtvercode"].value;
        if (a == null || a == "") {
            alert("Please Enter a value");
            return false;
        }
        if (b == null || b == "") {
            alert("Please Enter a value");
            return false;
        }
        if (c == null || c == "") {
            alert("Please Enter a value");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert("The Member has been added!");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

My Default.aspx.cs file looks like this:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
    @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\employees.mdf';
    Integrated Security=True");

    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO membership (FirstName, LastName, MembershipClass, VerificationCode) VALUES ('" + txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "', '" + dropmemberclass.Text + "', '" + txtvercode.Text + "')", conn);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    txtFirstName.Text = "";
    txtLastName.Text = "";
    txtvercode.Text = "";
    txtMemID.Text = "";
    txtmemdelete.Text = "";
    lblMemID.Text = "";
    lblMemIDSearch.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the code with this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
    if(txtFirstName.Text != "" && txtLastName.Text != "" && txtvercode.Text = "")//And so on...
    {
        @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\employees.mdf';
        Integrated Security=True");

        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO membership (FirstName, LastName, MembershipClass, VerificationCode) VALUES ('" + txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "', '" + dropmemberclass.Text + "', '" + txtvercode.Text + "')", conn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        txtFirstName.Text = "";
        txtLastName.Text = "";
        txtvercode.Text = "";
        txtMemID.Text = "";
        txtmemdelete.Text = "";
        lblMemID.Text = "";
        lblMemIDSearch.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Add more to the condition i added...

Comment: Hi Nirock,  I got it working now, All i had to do was put the if statement outside and then nest the rest of the SqlConnection bits inside the if statement and it workes like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) to each `TextBox`:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
                 ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
                 Text="First name is a required field"
                 ForeColor="red" 
                 runat=server>
```

This validates data both client side and server side so you don't need any of that Javascript code.

Comment: Hi nmat, i tried this as well. But this isn't the exact thing i was looking for. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

you can add any keys like primary key to the columns so it will not accept null value and add requiredfieldvalidator to your text boxes

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="myCustValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"  OnServerValidate="ServerFirstNameValid"></asp:CustomValidator>

protected void ServerFirstNameValid(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
   args.IsValid = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text.Trim());
   if (!args.IsValid)
         myCustValidator.ErrorMessage="First Name should not be Empty";
}
```